# Google Apps Script: Copy cell value to another sheet with condition to copy and position the value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with 4 sheets: "List", "Map N1", "Map N2" and "Map N3". It is supposed to work as a control for a deposit of Metallic Units.

"List" has these columns:

-MU (Metallic Unit)

-Weight

-Position (Level)

-Position (Letter)

-Position (Number)

-Arrival date and time

-Departure date and time

-Destination

-Status

-Observations

When a MU arrive, the data is entered and the column "Status" receive "Awaiting positioning" as value. When the MU is positioned within the deposit, the "Status" change to "Positioned". What I need to do is:

-When the "Status" change to "Positioned", copy the value of the respective MU column to one of the Maps, depending on the "Position (Level)". If the "Position (Level)" is "N1", it goes to "Map N1", "N2" to "Map N2" and so it goes.

-The Map sheets look like this:
[image: Map sheet]

-The MU value should position in the sheet according to the "Position (Letter)" and "Position (Number)" values. That way, the MU below should go to the sheet just like this image:
[image: List and Map sheet]

I've searched and managed to find this code:

```
function onEdit(event) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    if(s.getName() == "List" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == "Posicionada") {
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Map N1");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1).copyTo(target);    
    }
  }
```

The idea was to use this code to figure out how to copy the value automatically, and then adapt it to the positioning thing. But This isn't even copying the values to the other sheet.

Comment: It isn't copying because you are using the "moveTo" function

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I changed it to "copyTo". No results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **setValue()** instead of **moveTo**/**copyTo**.

```
 targetSheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(s.getRange(r.getRow(), 1, 1, 1).getValue());
```

Here is the rest of your code if you will need it.

It basically uses the reference in cell to get the correct sheet, column and row. As your columns are not original, I added a loop to cycle through the first row on the Map sheet and find the correct column.

```
function onEdit(event) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.range;
if(s.getName() === "Lista" && r.getColumn() === 9 && r.getValue() === "Posicionada") {
  var sheetname = s.getRange(r.getRow(),3).getValue();
  var columnRef = s.getRange(r.getRow(),4).getValue();
  var rowref = s.getRange(r.getRow(),5).getValue();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Mapa " + sheetname);
  var headers = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, targetSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().toString().split(",");
  var rows = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, targetSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().toString().split(",");

  //Getting The correct Column
  for (var i = 1; i < headers.length; i++) {
    if (headers[i] === columnRef) {
      break;
    }
  }

  var column = i + 1;

  //Getting the correct row
  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (Number(rows[i]) === rowref) {
      break;
    }
  }

  var row = i + 1;

  targetSheet.getRange(row,column).setValue(s.getRange(r.getRow(), 1, 1, 1).getValue()); 
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the columnRef will not receive "A, B, C..." values, actually there is "A1, A2, B1, B2..." so when this code receive the columnRef and read, for example "B1", it doesn't understand the number and ends up putting the value in the first column, but in the right row. The code is really good, but, to make it work like it needs to, I can only think of testing individually with many conditions the column, and I fear this will make the sheet really slow.

Comment: I adapted your code using:


    `var column;  if (columnRef === "A1") {  column = 2;  }`


And it works for A1, but I'd need to test A1 all the way to N2. You know a better way to test this?

Comment: I don't know if it's wrong to write many comments. But thanks to you everything is working. The code is kinda big, but it ended up like this: http://freetexthost.com/4mgqlkicuq (in lines 101 to 107, I subtracted those numbers because the grid of N2 and N3 is different, so this corrects the position).

Comment: That;s why I wrote a loop to scroll through the headers and find the relevant column: if (headers[i] === columnRef)

Comment: Well, I'm confused now. Before adding those conditions, no matter what was in the cells, it would always put the MU value in the column A, substituting the white numbers in blue background. But it's working now, I'll experiment on it later to optimize the code.

Comment: Could you give the output of this: Logger.log(headers)

Comment: I couldn't see the log, since I only know how to look in the debugger, and the onEdit() needs to be triggered in the spreadsheet. But I did this:
`SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(headers);`
And it returned the string "Range". I don't know if it has the same result, using this alert, if it needs to be done with the Logger, could you help me in seeing the logs?

Comment: if you type in Posicionada like norma, it will trigger the script and you can see the output of the logger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87034/discussion-between-bruno-vaz-and-akshin-jalilov).

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(event) {      
  var range = event.range;
  var fromRow = range.getRow();
  var fromCol = range.getColumn()
  ...
  s.getRange(fromRow, fromCol, 1, 1).copyTo(target);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!