# Get data from one full list to 3 separate sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have list of orders and need to make separate print sheet pages with 30 clients in each who has ordered something.
I use hide columns and rows script and tried to use importrange() , but imports hidden columns and rows too.
Maybe there is some other way that i could filter only clients with orders with functions or scripts, like query or filter?

Here is test spreadsheet: [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LAADLcx4y9jL3JQkmTXA6pxdlbOOprzXAgi-klei1ws/edit#gid=517903327)

Sheet "All" contains with all clients and orders.
Sheet "Print1" and "Print2" should have all clients who made orders (each sheet should have max 30 clients)

Comment: Have simply tried using a pivot chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to copy a row based on a cell value, try checking this related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11128778/5995040) or [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31997774/5995040).

Here is the code from post:

```
function copy2(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]); selects the first sheet in your spreadsheet
  var data=sh.getDataRange().getValues();// data is a 2D array, index0 = col A
  // so column k is index 10
  var target=new Array();// this is a new array to collect data
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){ // iterate in the array, row by row
    if (data[n][10]=="Done In The Past 30 Days"){ ;// if condition is true copy the whole row to target
    taget.push(data[n]);// copy the whole row
    }
    }
    if(target.length>0){// if there is something to copy
  var sh2=SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]); //second sheet of your spreadsheet
  sh2.getRange(1,1,target.length,target[0].length).setValues();// paste the selected values in the 2cond sheet in one batch write
  }
}
```

You can add a counter that will limit each copy per sheetID.

Hope this helps.