# Copying cells into multiple other cells with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

[Dummy Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HgeL8kyW9VN_eKaAzcI0UVE5p4_e1jFrti2yYphI1SM/edit?usp=sharing)

I am trying to create an app script for a google sheet that will copy certain cells based off other cells value.

In the dummy spreadsheet, I need a script that will copy F2 if A4 = U and put it in B4. if A4 = M it would copy G2 into C4 and if A4 = G it would put H2 into D4.

This would run for every row in range, so in this case A4 to A21. If B4, C4 or D4 have text in them it would ignore that row and proceed to the next row. it would also refresh the sheet after each row.

Lastly, an example of the output I am looking for for the script to do is I4:I21

Thank you for any help on this, let me know if anyone has any questions.

Comment: Could you provide us a sample of code you wrote and/or a example of the sheet ?

Comment: I am starting from scratch on this, so no code as of yet. I am a noob when it comes to coding. The link to the example of the sheet is in the comment at the top.

Comment: Check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996447/google-apps-script-copy-cell-value-to-another-sheet-with-condition-to-copy-and) and see if it will help you. It uses the `setValue()` method to set value of specified range. See [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) for more information regarding this method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get meaningful answers you always need to provide some code. Otherwise it just feels that this forum is giving a free scripting service.

However, to help you on your way

If you have set the code basics up you can then start to get the ranges of the cell values by doing the following (note that this won't work in GAS at the moment as it doesn't assign the variables yet):

```
var val = sheet.getRange("A4").getValue(); //you still need to assign the variable sheet to the sheet where all your values are
var DestRange = sheet.getRange("B4"); //your destination to copy to
var CopyRange = sheet.getRange("F2"); //the source you are copying
if(val = "U"){
CopyRange.CopyTo(DestRange)}

//Continue above script for the rest of your data ranges.
```

for info on how to assign your spreadsheet to a variable (e.g. "sheet" in the script) look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).

Hope this helps